# Phantom app can't identify token from Solana Pay QR code transaction

Tags: spl-token, phantom, solana-pay, phantom-wallet

I have a QR code generated with [@solana/pay](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/tree/master/core) that represents a transfer request with an SPL Token (token address: [K9fuM7y9SGgmydvREbdUe7GUMadXhUi7VzQk7Aiapcm](https://solana.fm/address/K9fuM7y9SGgmydvREbdUe7GUMadXhUi7VzQk7Aiapcm/metadata?cluster=mainnet-qn1)). When I scan this QR code I receive an error: "This contains a token that you don't own or we can't identify". As seen [here](https://solana.fm/address/4kzWUKHfMda1HRf6VzftgxEZaHnd7AgTZKczyrzDkod3) my wallet does have a few of these tokens which would mean that the Phantom app cannot identify the token, but I don't understand what could be wrong with it.

Has anyone come across this error before? Thank you!

This is the QR code which would be decoded as a valid Solana Pay link:

solana:8ZFBM9hBL5jVyXHo2nT1VyHNfpNXy1cJQRMzr1L7Nvuj?amount=0.001&spl-token=K9fuM7y9SGgmydvREbdUe7GUMadXhUi7VzQk7Aiapcm&reference=xoWcEKFZjZWuy52nCPc1wMxDQmcPzK9wRGrHWcVYTHe&label=Soma%2BMarket

[image]

Comment: Try using Solflare or Glow and see if it still throws an error, it might just be Phantom.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @Hi_I'mJohn ! Solflare does indeed work when scanning.